# SQL union and removing duplicates base on priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please have a look at SQLFiddle below 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dd713/2/0

I have two tables. And I union both tables to get the data that I am looking for 
But I would like to remove the duplicates and use info from table1 as the priority

currently the table looks like this (info1 comes from table1 and info2 comes from table2)

```
1, info1
2, info1
3, info1
3, info2
4, info1
4, info2
5, info1
5, info2
6, info2
7, info2
```

So the end result will look like below

```
1, info1
2, info1
3, info1
4, info1
5, info1
6, info2
7, info2
```

how can I do this?

thank you

Comment: @cha yep, I've got a MailExeception page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this request using two unions:

```
-- fully functional example using your provided data.
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (ID INT, Value NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (ID INT, Value NVARCHAR(20))

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT @table1 VALUES (1, 'info1');
INSERT @table1 VALUES (2, 'info1');
INSERT @table1 VALUES (3, 'info1');
INSERT @table2 VALUES (3, 'info2');
INSERT @table1 VALUES (4, 'info1');
INSERT @table2 VALUES (4, 'info2');
INSERT @table1 VALUES (5, 'info1');
INSERT @table2 VALUES (5, 'info2');
INSERT @table2 VALUES (6, 'info2');
INSERT @table2 VALUES (7, 'info2');
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

-- this is not the most efficient way to go, I did this to show the steps involved to obtain your desired result
-- a more efficient solution follows.
SELECT T.ID, T.Value FROM (

    -- only appear in table1
    SELECT * FROM @table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM @table2)

    -- appear in both table, but choose element from table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM @table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @table2)

    -- only appear in table 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM @table2 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM @table1)

) T 
ORDER BY T.ID

-- if you prefer more efficiency and without a UNION, try this:
SELECT
     CASE WHEN A.ID IS NOT NULL THEN A.ID ELSE B.ID END AS ID
     ,CASE WHEN A.Value IS NOT NULL THEN A.Value ELSE B.Value END AS Value

FROM @table1 A
    FULL OUTER JOIN @table2 B ON A.ID=B.ID;
```

Comment: I think this will work. Thanks. I will try it tomorrow. thank you!

Comment: The CASE when does not prioritize table 1 for some reason. So The Two union works great. Thank you

Comment: The second answer, using CASE WHEN, will not work as expected if Value column allows NULL. Otherwise this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are using UNION / UNION ALL to Get results from these two tables, I guess you can do something like this

```
;WITH CTE (ID , Info, rn)
AS(
  SELECT * ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  ID, INFO_Col1 ORDER BY ID ASC) 
  FROM (    
  SELECT ID, INFO_Col1 FROM table_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, INFO_Col2 FROM Table_2)Query
  )
  SELECT Info1, Info2 
  FROM CTE
  WHERE  rn = 1
```